# Push loop results into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
  function generateObject(){

    var newarray = [],
        thing;

     //console.log(matrixData);

     for(var i = 0; i < matrixData.data.length; i++){
        console.log('Date: '+matrixData.data[i][0]);
        console.log('Total: '+matrixData.data[i][1]);
        thing = {};
        for(var y = 0; y < matrixData.data[i][2].data.length; y++){
            console.log(matrixData.data[i][2].data[y]);

        }
        // newarray.push(matrixData.data[i][0]);
        // console.log(newarray);
     }

}
```

what I am currently getting from the console log I would need to push inside an array which would look like this:

```
[

    [matrixData.data[i][0] matrixData.data[i][2].data[y] matrixData.data[i][1]]
    [matrixData.data[i][0] matrixData.data[i][2].data[y] matrixData.data[i][1]]
    [matrixData.data[i][0] matrixData.data[i][2].data[y] matrixData.data[i][1]]

]
```

I would then 'return' the 'newarray' inside the 'generateObject' function and pass it inside a jQuery load template.

I am having problems achieving the above array.

I would expect and end result like this ion the console:

http://jsfiddle.net/knp8A/3/

Comment: add a fiddle that will be better, or at least show what are you getting

Comment: put `return newarray` at the end of `generateObject` function and get it in jquery on load

Comment: your output matrix makes no sense - you're showing three elements in each row, but both `i` and `y` are variables.

Answer (score 2):

Simply push the objects, and return `newarray`

```
  function generateObject(){

    var newarray = [],
        thing;

     //console.log(matrixData);

     for(var i = 0; i < matrixData.data.length; i++){

        console.log('Date: '+matrixData.data[i][0]);
        console.log('Total: '+matrixData.data[i][1]);
        thing = {};

        for(var y = 0; y < matrixData.data[i][2].data.length; y++){
            //console.log(matrixData.data[i][2].data[y]);
            newarray.push(matrixData.data[i][2].data[y]);
        }

        // newarray.push(matrixData.data[i][0]);
        // console.log(newarray);
     }

     return newarray;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the date and total in each row only the 2 values

Comment: Try to check the values of Array[2].

Comment: Yes I need 2 more values which are the date and the total so each array should have 4 values and not 2

Comment: @Alex please describe your problem in more detail.  Your example shows _three_ elements in each row, not four.  It's completely unclear how you want to map the three-dimensional data set you have in `matrixData` into the two dimensions you've shown in the question.

Comment: @Alnitak I am sorry this (matrixData.data[i][2].data[y]) is actually returning 2 values that is why I meant four, my mistake, would that make sense or shall I put a full jsfiddle up?

Comment: I have updated the question with the expected end result